# Splitting contents of a parenthesis to two lines

Tags: equations, braces, split

I have read about braces spanning more than two lines [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics), and in many other places but am not sure about the mistake i've made in the following code,

```
\begin{align}
p\left( {l,m,n} \right) &= \left( {\frac{{{A_1}}}{{{A_1} + {A_2} + 
{A_3}}},\frac{{{A_2}}}{{{A_1} + {A_2} + {A_3}}}, \right. \nonumber \\ 
&\qquad \left. {} \frac{{{A_3}}}{{{A_1} + {A_2} + {A_3}}}} \right)
\end{align}
```

It compiles and gives the desired result, but also returns the error

> Missing } inserted. \end{align}

Please help me with this issue,
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: (i) please, convert your code snippet to complete small document begining with`\documentclas{...}` and ending with `end{document}`. (ii) your equation is probably generated with some equation editor, consequently it has many unnecessary curly braces (iii) check with some editor, if all braces are paired. welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after cleaning "forest" of superfluous curly braces  in your code sniped, i obtain:

```
\begin{align}
p(l,m,n) 
    & = \left(\frac{A_1}{A_1} + A_2 + A_3,
        \frac{A_2}{A_1} + A_2 + A_3, \right. \nonumber \\
    &\qquad \left.\frac{A_3}{A_1} + A_2 + A_3 \right)
\end{align}
```

or,

```
\begin{equation}
p(l,m,n) 
      = \left(\frac{A_1}{A_1} + A_2 + A_3,\;
        \frac{A_2}{A_1} + A_2 + A_3,\;
        \frac{A_3}{A_1} + A_2 + A_3 \right)
\end{equation}
```

which gives

[image]

and (to my taste, better looking):

[image]

without any warnings or errors.

**addendum:**

in two column document the second option gives to wide equation. beside first option is worth to consider `multline` math environment:

```
\begin{multline}
p\left( {l,m,n} \right)
    = \left(\frac{A_1}{A_1} + A_2 + A_3,\right.     \\
        \left.\frac{A_2}{A_1} + A_2 + A_3,
              \frac{A_3}{A_1} + A_2 + A_3 \right)
\end{multline}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg, oh, yes, i overlooked them :(

Comment: @Zako thanks a lot for the answer.. I did clear the forest myself and it worked..I converted a whole document from mathtype and did not want to remove those braces. I prefer the second option but unfortunately it does not fit well in a two column format

Comment: @manoj, instead `align` see, if `multline` better fit your needs. i will add this option asap.